# Calling php scripts with parameters and setting result in viewbag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, viewbag

I'm having trouble calling php scripts from Java Script and then using that result to set view bag values for my controller.
Here is the code behind:

```
<script>
var model = '<% = this %>';
var data = { NAMEPARAM: model.name }

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#AlertButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "www/CustomScripts.php",
        data: data
    }).success(function(data) {
        //need to set the returned message in view bag here.
    }).error(function (data) {
         alert("An error occurred while processing request")
        });
    });
});
</script>

<button id ="AlertButton" type="submit" class="btn green"> Alert </button>
<div id="PHPResult"> @ViewBag.message </div>
```

The problem I'm facing above, is to set the returned success message, in my ViewBag and then showing it on the screen. I know how to directly set the result inside the html div, but I need to set it inside the Viewbag

Also the way that I'm passing the name parameter to the php script. Is that the correct way, or is there a better way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a reason to involve the ViewBag here. You're not doing a postback to MVC, so there's no way to populate it. It's a transaction between the HTML/Javascript and the PHP webservice only.

So, it's actually relatively simple:

```
<script>
var model = '<% = this %>';
var data = { NAMEPARAM: model.name }

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#AlertButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "www/CustomScripts.php",
      data: data
    }).success(function(data) {
     $("#PHPResult").html(data); //assuming "data" is a user-friendly string
    }).error(function (data) {
      alert("An error occurred while processing request")
    });
  });
});
</script>

<button id ="AlertButton" type="submit" class="btn green"> Alert </button>
<div id="PHPResult"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah i know how to do it this way. But, the problem that I am facing is to set the result returned from php service inside the view bag. The reason for this is, inside the controller I need to do some operations based upon that result. So my question is, is there any way to set the result from the php web service inside the view bag. Even if you can refer me to any link or help material, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: At the moment you're returning the data direct to the client-side webpage, and bypassing the controller entirely. Your code will run after all your controller code has finished, and the page has been rendered to the user. It will run on the user's machine, not on the server. To do what you want, you can either (a) move your calculation code into the javascript, or (b) call the PHP method from your C# code - for this, the second answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512951/best-practice-for-c-sharp-calling-php-which-then-queries-the-database